# How do I get the value from a checkbox in Yii?

Tags: php, checkbox, yii, yii-chtml

I have a checkbox:

```
echo CHtml::checkBox("My checkbox", true, array());
```

How do I read its value through Yii? I know there's `activeCheckBox` which will link the value to a model attribute, but I don't want to create a new model class just to read a single value from a checkbox. Do I have to assign it an ID and get the value with javascript? Seems pretty absurd to me that Yii would have a function to create a checkbox but no way to retrieve its value afterwards… Also, since dynamic attributes don't work in Yii I can't just create an attribute on some other model that I have available.

How are the `CHtml::checkBox` elements in Yii intended to be used?

Comment: the html will contain id and name using CHtml::checkBox(), you can get using javascript or will be post in postdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just  use  $_POST['My checkbox'] ;

CHtml::checkBox  just  generate an input tag for you .

you can open  html  source  and see it .

Comment: I just realized this myself... I guess it was kind of a stupid question. I'm not really into the whole web/PHP/Yii mindset at all, I try to stay away from it as much as possible :)